# PHP: storing regex expression as define

Tags: php, regex

I have this line:

```
 ->addValidator('regex', false,array('#^[a-zA-Z0-9_\- .\/\'\",*&+]+$#'))
```

and want to reuse the regex expression in further code

I tried to store the expression as:

```
 define ("ALNUMREG","#^[a-zA-Z0-9_\- .\/\'\",*&+]+$#");
```

but this causes the validator fails.

This fails too:

```
function getMyAlnumRegex() {

   return '#^[a-zA-Z0-9_\- .\/\'\",*&+]+$#';

}

 ->addValidator('regex', false,array(getMyAlnumRegex()))
```

Any ideas?

Regards
Tom

Comment: What does *This fails too* mean? Do you get any errors? Also show us your attempt with the constant, don't see why this shouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

You just want to save a defined regular expression and then just pass it to your function or something right?  Hope this helps, just swap out my **$pattern** variable in the code below.

```
<?php

    $string = "I visited a web site todaywe are looking for web websites testing.";
    $pattern = '/\bweb\b/i'; // <- this is your pattern. 

    $match = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    //$match use this to test for true / false, it returns 1 if true...
    echo $matches[0] . '<br>';//echo the first match if there is one.

    if (preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
        echo "we found a match yay.";
    } else {
        echo "NO match was found in the string";
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to escape (backslash prefixed) sequences being interpreted by PHP parser and not by regex parser.

Try to use `nowdoc` mechanism to store regex patterns.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

> ... no parsing is done inside a nowdoc.

Answer (score 0):

After you claimed it must work I looked for other reasons and it turned out I had a mismach i character coding between the php file containing the regex and one with the validator. 
I set all to UTF-8 and it works as charm :)
Thank you!
Regards
Tom